# Javascript web3 calls Solidity contract function with extra parameter?

Tags: solidity, truffle

In the http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop example, there is the following contract, and the function `adopt(uint petId)` has only one parameter.

```
contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;
        return petId;
    }

    function getAdopters() public returns (address[16]) {
        return adopters;
    }
}
```

However, in the javascript code `app.js`, the `handleAdopt` function call the contract function using the following code.

```
  App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    adoptionInstance = instance;
    return adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, {from: account});
  })
```

The function is called with the extra object `{from: account}`. Why? And is this parameter discarded in the solidity code?

BTW, there is an undefined global variable `web3`? Is the value be assigned by the MetaMask extension?

Answer (score 1):

The extra argument object `{from: account}` specifies details about how to send the transaction. The fields in this argument object are not passed to the Solidity function.

In your example it specifies which account to make the transaction `from`. In the context of the code you're talking about, `account` refers to `accounts[0]` which is the first account available in the `web3` instance you have access to. If you remove this argument, the from account defaults to `accounts[0]`.

[This web3 doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) shows the other fields you can include in the extra argument object. Eg if you wanted to specify the maximum gas the transaction should use it could look like this `adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, {from: accounts[0], gas: 1000000})`

To answer your second question, [this bit of the tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop#instantiating-web3) has a code snippet that attempts to get the web3 object from different sources. It checks if it has been injected, which is what MetaMask does if it is installed and unlocked, if it can't find an injected web3 object, it will try to use a local web3 instance available at `http://localhost:7545`, the ip that Ganache uses. So make sure you either have MetaMask installed and unlocked or Ganache running to get access to a web3 object.